# SharePoint Default Styles

Tags: css, sharepoint

I'm building a custom web part for SharePoint and I'm trying to use the default styles so when people theme the site, it will theme with it.

I've found a couple of decent sites that show the different styles like:
http://www.sharepointcustomization.com/resources/tipstricks/wss_cssguide.htm

but I'm looking for something that has better examples.  Specifically, I'm looking for a good table style that I can add.

Does anyone know of a site that shows the different SharePoint CSS styles with examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Heather Solomon's blog is the multimate reference](http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm) for Sharepoint 2007 CSS (the link you posted is for SharePoint 2003). You can also use [developer toolbar](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) to find the CSS class you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that ultimate reference was exactly what I was looking for.

The link to the developer toolbar you provided isn't there anymore, but I'm assuming that you were mentioning Firebug or the IE developer toolbar which is how I was grabbing the styles before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a custom webpart, consider SPGridView for your tables, I believe it will use the standard sharepoint List table styles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx